# Duplicates in output of an inner join

Tags: postgresql

I am bringing together two tables within PostgreSQL through an inner join. The first table is an exported adwords file (adwords_final.)  The second one is simply just a reference to the "campaigns" column that are to be displayed within Microsoft excel.  These occur only once per campaign while the adwords data contains multiple entries per campaign as there is the factor/column of date.

I have used the following query to output this to a csv file

```
COPY (SELECT * FROM adwords_final INNER JOIN mk_kw ON "mk_kw"."Key"  =  "adwords_final"."Key") TO 'C:\Users\iantu\Desktop\Performance Marketing\Report Outputs\adwords_final.csv' WITH CSV HEADER;
```

The problem is that my new csv file contains many duplicates.   Am I using the correct command here or should I switch to something like a loop?

Columns from adwords_final

```
 Week, Keyword state,   Keyword Campaign,    Ad group ,   Status , Max. CPC  ,  Impressions, Interactions ,   Interaction Types ,  Interaction Rate    Avg. Cost ,  Cost  ,  Clicks ,Avg. position ,  Conversions, Quality score ,  Ad relevance  ,  Landing page experience ,Expected clickthrough rate , Qual. score (hist.) ,Ad relevance (hist.)   , Landing page experience (hist.) ,Expected clickthrough rate (hist.)  ,Search Impr. share  ,Match type , First position CPC , Top of page CPC ,First page CPC , Impressions with average ctr    ,Impressions with above average ctr , Impressions with below average ctr  ,Impressions with below average lp exp ,  Impressions with average lp exp ,Impressions with above average lp exp ,  Impressions with below average Ad Rel ,  Impressions with  average ad rel  ,  Impressions with above average ad rel ,  QSxIMP , Key
```

Columns from mk_kw

```
Language,   Network, Main Keyword,    Cluster Keyword 1 ,  Match Type,  Key
```

Thanks

Comment: Inner join is shorthand for left inner join.
Your `adwords_final` contains dates * campaign, your right file contains only one record per campaign.

As a result, your file will always contain multiple records for a campaign. Or do you get the records already in `adwords_final` dobule?

Comment: There are no duplicates within adwords_final.  Campaign and dates are both their own seperate column.  I have updated the thread to include all columns within each table.